# When is the cooldown on Lich Bane's proc reset?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lich Bane has the passive:

> Unique – Spellblade: After using an ability, your next basic attack
>   deals bonus magic damage equal to 50 + 75% of your ability power. 2
>   second cooldown.

When is the counter for the 2 second cooldown started?  Is it on *creation* or *consumption* of the passive?  As an illustration, consider this timeline:

- 0 Seconds: Kayle casts Righteous Fury.  This *creates* the Spellblade Passive
- 2 Seconds: Kayle stands around
- 2.1 Seconds: Kayle Autoattacks Caitlin.  This *consumes* the Spellblade Passive
- 2.3 Seconds: Kayle casts Reckoning on Caitlin.  **Is spellblade created again?**
- 2.5 Seconds: Kayle Autottacks Caitlin.

The critical point is the 4th step, whe Kayle casts her Q.  At that point it's been 2.3 seconds since the first instance of spellblade was created, but only .2 since the first instance was consumed.  Will a new instance of spellblade be created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like similar ability proc effects (Trinity Force, Sheen, Iceborne Gauntlet), the internal cooldown starts when you attack *and consume* the damage proc. Therefore, Kayle casting Reckoning in this scenario will not proc Lichbane.

Comment: You can always check by looking at the item in your inventory. Getting the buff will display it above your HP/Mana. Using it will consume the buff and the item will have a blue overlay during the 2 second CD.